# Showing That $1/2+2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ Is Not Increasing On Any $(a,b)\supset\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

There is an exercise in Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* that states:

> **Exercise 5.3.7. (b) Show that the function**
>   $$g(x)=\begin{cases}
> x/2+x^2\sin(1/x)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\\
> 0&\text{ if }x=0
> \end{cases}$$
>   **is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies $g'(0)\geq0$. Now, prove that $g$ is *not* increasing over any open interval containing $0$.**

First of all, I know that for $x=0$,
$$g'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x/2+x^2\sin(1/x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\left[\frac{1}{2}+x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\geq0,$$
and for $x\neq0$,
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{2}+2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$
Hence,
$$g'(x)=\begin{cases}
1/2+2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\\
1/2&\text{ if }x=0,
\end{cases}$$
and $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I do not know how to formally show that if $(a,b)$ is an open interval containing $0$, then $g$ is not increasing on it; the idea I have is to keep in mind that as $x$ approaches $0$, it oscillates 'faster,' and you can thus always find two different points $x,y\in(a,b)$ such that $g'(x)>0$ and $g'(y)<0$. Is this a valid assertion? If so, how can I go about showing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that would work. Since $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ it would be increasing on $(a,b)$ if and only if $g'\ge0$ over $(a,b)$.  So, you only need to find a point $c$ in $(a,b)$ where $g'(c)<0.$

Try a point $c$ where $\cos(1/c)=1$.  These points would be of the form ${1\over 2n\pi}$.
We have
$$\textstyle
g'({\textstyle{1\over 2n\pi}})= {1\over2}+ {1\over n\pi}\cdot\sin(2n\pi) -\cos(2n\pi)={1\over2}+0-1={-1\over2}.
$$

As you can select $n$ so large that ${1\over 2n\pi}$ is in $(a,b)$, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the right way. In your expression for $g'(x)$, you see that the term $\cos(1/x)$ oscillates infinitely many times between $-1$ and $+1$ on any open interval containing zero, and because of this fact, such an interval contains infinitely many little subintervals where $g'>0$ and infinitely many where $g'<0$.