# Let $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin{1/x}$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f'(0)=1$ but $f$ is not monotonic in any interval around $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=x+2x^2\sin{1/x}$ for $x\neq0$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f'(0)=1$ but $f$ is not monotonic in any interval around $0$.

I have shown the first part. How to show its monotonicity part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x+2x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}, \ \ x\neq 0, \\0, \ \ x = 0\end{cases}$$
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}1+4x\sin\frac{1}{x} - 2\cos\frac{1}{x}, \ \ x \in U^\circ_\varepsilon(0)  \\ 1,  \ \ x = 0\end{cases}$$

So, if $f$ is monotonic, say increasing, on an interval containing $0$ then you must have $f'(x) \ge 0, \ \ \forall x \in U_\varepsilon(0)$, i.e
$$1+4x\sin\frac{1}{x} - 2\cos\frac{1}{x} \ge 0,  \ \ \forall x \in U_\varepsilon(0)$$
However, you can always find a point $c$ such that $f'(c) < 0$, see this [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114856/752069).

The converse ($f$ - decreasing) is similar.

Comment: I think it should be $-2\cos{1/x}$, right?

Comment: @madhurask Yes, right. That is a typo to be fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f'(\frac  1{2n \pi})$ and $f'(\frac  1{(4n+1) \pi /2})$. Check that for large $n$ the first one is negative and the  second one is positive and any interval of the type $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ contains these points for large $n$. If $f$ is  monotonic in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$  the $f'$ would not change sign. This proves that $f$ is not  monotonic in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for any $-\epsilon>0$.